# Recuperar dados JSON via POST

Tags: php, json

Tenho um Aplicativo que manda as cordeadas via POST e recupero via JSON, porem não estou conseguindo separar as coordenadas que chegam em uma array.

Segue um exemplo

```
$datas = file_get_contents('php://input');  
$encoded = json_decode($datas);

$id_usuario_rastreio =  $encoded->{'id_usuario'};
$id_grupo =  $encoded->{'id_grupo'};
$id_token =  $encoded->{'token'};
```

Preciso recuperar agora a **locationList** e separar para inserir no banco.

```
{
        "id_grupo": "20",
        "id_usuario": "21",
        "token": "0123456",
        "locationList":[{"date":"Feb 27, 2018 12:32:08 PM","latitude_rastreio":"-10.5267176","longitude_rastreio":"-10.5702931"},{"date":"Feb 27, 2018 12:33:08 PM","latitude_rastreio":"-10.5267176","longitude_rastreio":"-10.5702931"}]
}
```

Segue o teste sendo realizado no POSTMAN
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Bem a função [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-decode.php) se você quer transformar de json para array a sintaxe é:

```
$encode = json_decode($datas, TRUE);
```

A partir do momento que você transforma em um array você tem que capturar trabalhando como array por índices/ valores, quando você faz `$enconded->` é uma forma de acessar um objeto.

Seu json....

```
{
        "id_grupo": "20",
        "id_usuario": "21",
        "token": "0123456",
        "locationList":[{"date":"Feb 27, 2018 12:32:08 PM","latitude_rastreio":"-10.5267176","longitude_rastreio":"-10.5702931"},{"date":"Feb 27, 2018 12:33:08 PM","latitude_rastreio":"-10.5267176","longitude_rastreio":"-10.5702931"}]
}
```

... convetido para array fica:

```
array (
  'id_grupo' => '20',
  'id_usuario' => '21',
  'token' => '0123456',
  'locationList' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'date' => 'Feb 27, 2018 12:32:08 PM',
      'latitude_rastreio' => '-10.5267176',
      'longitude_rastreio' => '-10.5702931',
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
      'date' => 'Feb 27, 2018 12:33:08 PM',
      'latitude_rastreio' => '-10.5267176',
      'longitude_rastreio' => '-10.5702931',
    ),
  ),
)
```

Logo o locationList é um array com informações e você deve buscar os dados conforme se trabalha com arrays. Aí depende do que e como capturar, buscar todos os locationList pegando com foreach etc.